# Linq to Entities - Contains not working

Tags: c#, linq

I thought I understood how the LINQ contains works, however I am not getting my statement to filter the results.

In this case I would have expected the first 2 records to be returned, however I am getting all of the results back.

Why is my LINQ Contains not filtering out the data?

```
MYTABLE:
CODE   VERSION   STRING_ID
A1     1         AAA
A1     1         BBB
A1     1         CCC
A1     1         DDD

List<String> ListStrings has values of:
AAA
BBB

My Query:
            var query = context.MYTABLE.Where(x => x.CODE == "A1" && x.VERSION == "1");

            if (ListStrings!= null)
            {
                query.Where(x => ListStrings.Contains(x.STRING_ID));
            }

            return query.ToList();
```

Comment: `query = query.Where(..)`

Answer (score 5):

The [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method itself will return an `IEnumerable` collection that has the filtering applied, so you need to set your query object equal to it :

```
query = query.Where(x => ListStrings.Contains(x.STRING_ID));
```